# How can I make the Wordpress comment checkbox mandatory/required before posting a comment?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, checkbox, required

I disabled the Wordpress function 'Show comments cookies opt-in checkbox, allowing comment author cookies to be set.' but I added a checkbox in the comment form manually because I wanted to change the label of the checkbox.

I did this by adding the following code to the functions.php of my child theme:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_default_fields', 'tu_comment_form_change_cookies_consent' );
function tu_comment_form_change_cookies_consent( $fields ) {
    $commenter = wp_get_current_commenter();

    $consent   = empty( $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) ? '' : ' checked="checked"';

    $fields['cookies'] = '<p class="comment-form-cookies-consent"><input id="wp-comment-cookies-consent" name="wp-comment-cookies-consent" type="checkbox" value="yes"' . $consent . ' />' .
                     '<label for="wp-comment-cookies-consent">By using this comment form you agree with our Privacy Policy</label></p>';
    return $fields;

}
```

This is working fine but now I wanna have this checkbox mandatory so that the user has to check it before pressing the 'Post comment' button.

So if the checkbox is unchecked, the user should see a error message when clicking on the 'Post comment' button.

How can I do that? All the suggestions I found so far are not working, like for example adding 'required' behind the input id or name.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Adding the [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#The_required_attribute) to the input field should be enough to prevent a form submission. Since according to you that's "not working" we'll need to see some sample code (or a live URL) to understand what's going on and provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter hook just before comment data is set. It is `preprocess_comment`. In that hook I have checked if the checkbox is set or not. If not it will block to post comment data.

```
function wpso_verify_policy_check( $commentdata ) {
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type( $_POST['comment_post_ID'] ) ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['wp-comment-cookies-consent'] ) ) {
            wp_die( '<strong>' . __( 'WARNING: ' ) . '</strong>' . __( 'You must accept the Privacy Policy.' ) . '<p><a href="javascript:history.back()">' . __( '&laquo; Back' ) . '</a></p>');
        }
    }
    return $commentdata;
}

add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'wpso_verify_policy_check' );
```

Edit: Added post type conditional so that this check is applied to `post` post type only.

Comment: Thank you big time!
Your answer is doing the job BUT...
Now I've got another problem: The same check if the checkbox is set or not is now also applied for Woocommerce reviews with the problem being that the actual checkbox is not shown there.
That means, if I wanna submit a review for a Woocommerce product the error message ('You mus accept the Privacy Policy') appears but there is no checkbox to actually accept it. Again, for post comments it is working fine.
Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks again, that is doing the job :)
Is there an easy way how I can show the error message on the same page as a browser popup instead displaying it on a separate page? I just wanna avoid the additional click on the back button.

Comment: For that I guess you can use JavaScript for the validate and block form submission if checkbox is not checked. Not sure but this could work. https://pastebin.com/PdaTC0Z6